# AngularJS 1.5 with component and Routing

Tags: angularjs

I am looking for guidance or article that show how to routing work with Angularjs 1.5 components. I can see ui-router 1.0 having feature but not sure.
Appreciate help on this.

Comment: How is this too broad? It's been flagged by people who've never answered a question about angularjs.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfectly valid question as there is no documentation on the [official website](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/) right now.

However the basic component routing is very straightforward:

```
.state('chat', {
      url: '/chat',
      //templateurl: 'views/chat.html'
      //template: '<chat></chat>'
      component: 'chat'
});
```

In previous versions you would use the template or templateurl properties to load a component.

The new 1.0 version adds a component property.
In the example above the chat state is called, the chat component will be loaded.

The rest of ui-touter features work the same with components.

Comment: Thanks for reply, so with this new approach we are replacing template/tempareurl and controller with component. is that correct?

Comment: @nikudale, yes exactly.

Comment: Hi....I found [link](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component) for ui-router routing for component